# Hibernate performance issues

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, jpa

I am currently facing a performance problem with Hibernate and Postgresql.

I have this query (I use Criteria API with JPA MetaModel) :

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Object[]> cq = cb.createQuery(Object[].class);
cq.from(MyEntity.class);
cq.multiselect(
  root.get(MyEntity_.id),
  root.get(MyEntity_.name)
);

criteriaQuery.where(
  root.get(MyEntity_.link).in(links)
);

Query query = entityManager.createQuery(cq);

long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
List<Object[]> results = query.getResultList();
System.out.println("Query execution time : " + System.currentTimeMillis() - start);
```

Note that variable "links" is a collection of entities (size of collection is not limited but my query is executed with 289 elements).

When I execute this query, I can see that the following SQL is executed :

```
SELECT e.id, e.name FROM my_table e WHERE e.link_id IN (?, ?, ? ..... ?);
```

A prepared statement is executed by hibernate and query execution time is about 4.5 seconds.

If I change my query:

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Object[]> cq = cb.createQuery(Object[].class);
cq.from(MyEntity.class);
cq.multiselect(
  root.get(MyEntity_.id),
  root.get(MyEntity_.name)
);

criteriaQuery.where(
  root.get(MyEntity_.link).get(Link_.id).in(ids)
);

Query query = entityManager.createQuery(cq);

long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
List<Object[]> results = query.getResultList();
System.out.println("Query execution time : " + System.currentTimeMillis() - start);
```

Now, variable "ids" is a set of all link entities id and the following SQL query is now executed:

```
SELECT e.id, e.name FROM my_table e WHERE e.link_id IN (1, 2, 3, 4, ..... 289);
```

A simple statement is executed by hibernate and query execution time is about 100 milliseconds.

I searched in hibernate source and in driver source code but I can't understand:

- Why first query use a prepared statement and not the other.
- Why first query is so slow !

Note that I tried to execute my query with plain jdbc (using a PreparedStatement) and the execution time is about 100 milliseconds. The problem seems to come from PreparedStatement with hibernate but I can't understand why.

Note that I use the following version:

- Hibernate 4.2.2-Final
- postgresql-9.3-1102-jdbc41
- Database is Postgresql 9.3.1

Any suggestions ?

Thank you very much.